# function.call in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript

What is the shortest way of writing the following JavaScript as CoffeeScript?

```
var obj = {};

(function(){
  this.foo = "bar";
}).call(obj);
```

I can do this:

```
obj = {}

(->
  @foo = "bar"
).call obj
```

But is there a way to get rid of the parentheses around the function definition? This would almost work:

```
do =>
  @foo = "bar"
```

...except that the fat arrow operator '=>' automatically binds the function to the current value of 'this'. Is there a way to specify an alternative 'this' value when using the fat arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get rid of the parentheses, but you can write that function in a single line.

```
(-> @foo = 'bar').call obj
```

Comment: Ok, thought so but wasn't sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should accept Dogbert's answer. But if you're literally looking for the shortest way to write your code, the answer is

```
obj.foo = 'bar'
```

Resist the temptation to overuse anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

You had the answer from the start, but this should be added:

```
obj = {}

do (obj) ->
  obj.foo = "bar"
```

which compiles to

```
(function(obj){
  return obj.foo = 'bar';
})(obj);
```